# Как отсортировать порты с помощью Python

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток! Имеется файл **.txt** со списком

```
ip:port
178.237.187.66:53389
82.116.48.210:50000
213.184.149.46:60000
109.74.133.46:4455
78.110.245.206:3398
89.109.52.230:1001
88.135.48.69:3398
84.201.142.138:50000
89.250.150.68:50000
109.195.115.45:2020
46.172.46.206:50001
95.80.124.61:43389
46.172.62.46:60000
62.33.157.26:2020
80.243.1.242:63389
212.220.203.147:55555
185.78.29.72:63389
37.195.232.8:4489
178.49.148.75:60000
87.103.201.134:3398
```

Как мне разделить по портам, в отдельные файы **3398.txt**, **4489.txt**, и т.д

Comment: Самому сделать не судьба?

Comment: не получается, хотябы дайте напрвление в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Google/yandex/duckduckgo в помощь

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста посказку как мне именно сформулировать поисковой запрос?

Comment: пример декомпозиции составного вопроса: 1. «python как прочитать строки из файла». 2. «python как разбить строку по разделителю». 3. «python как создать файл с указанным именем». 4. «python как дописать в файл значение переменной». 5. доп. запрос: «python что такое массив и словарь и как с ними работать»

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать

Comment: Из прочитанных рекомендациий я так и не понял, как мне содавать файл с именем нужного мне порта и какое регулярное выражение мне использовать?

Comment: см. третий и второй из предложенных мною простых вопросов (в любом поисковике пишете текст вопроса, и читаете найденную информацию). почему я упомянул второй, в то время как вы спрашиваете про неупомянутые мною регулярные выражения? потому что регулярные выражения здесь не нужны. достаточно «python как разбить строку по разделителю».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас не получится, то могу предложить данное решение:

1. Создание файла и его открытие на чтение (в коде я добавил обращение к файлу через переменную `file` (*можно назвать переменную по-другому*)):

```
with open('file1.txt') as file:
```

2. `file.read()` - читаю содержимое файла,

   `file.read().split('\n')` - разделяю строки по символу `\n` и привожу к списку,

   далее через `for` итерируюсь по списку. Я применил `enumerate()`, чтобы автоматически получить индекс элемента последовательности. Данная функция позволяет избавиться от необходимости инициировать и обновлять отдельную переменную-счётчик. (*`k` - индекс, `i` - элемент*).

```
for k, i in enumerate(file.read().split('\n')):
```

3. Так как первая строка в файле - `ip:port`, то просто в условии игнорируем первую строку (**индексация элементов начинается с 0**)

```
if k != 0:
```

4. Разделяем строку, получаем последний элемент и дописываем `.txt`: `178.237.187.66:53389` -> `53389` -> `53389.txt`

```
name_file = str(i.split(":")[-1].strip()) + '.txt'
```

5. Создаём файл, именуем его и открываем на запись

```
file_2 = open(name_file, 'w')
```

6. Записываем в файл первый элемент из списка: `['178.237.187.66', '53389']` -> `'178.237.187.66'` и **закрываем файл**

```
file_2.write(i.split(':')[0])
file_2.close()
```

Полный код:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file:
    for k, i in enumerate(file.read().split('\n')):
        if k != 0:
            name_file = str(i.split(":")[-1].strip()) + '.txt'
            file_2 = open(name_file, 'w')
            file_2.write(i.split(':')[0])
            file_2.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Comment: @Morbius Не за что, если вас ответ устроил, оцените его)

Comment: Поскажите пожалуйста, в файле имеются ip адреса c одинаковым портом, как сделать чтобы записывались все ip с одинаковым портом?

Comment: @Morbius используйте в качестве ключа `a`

Comment: @Morbius Данный ключ позволяет дозаписывать значения (также когда будете записывать данные в файл, то не забудьте к строке для записи в файл добавить `\n`, чтобы каждая запись начиналась с новой строки)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте такой вариант (правда нужен `pandas`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ports.txt',sep=':')  # здесь путь к файлу

for port,ip in df.groupby('port'):
    ip.to_csv(f'{port}.txt',sep=':',index=False)  # перед {port} укажите путь к папке
```